# Doctrine Annotaion Exception

Tags: exception, doctrine, annotations, mapping

I have 5 servers running the same app (Zend + Doctrine) and on the last one server (installed recently) im I'm getting this exception:

```
Application error Exception information:

Message: Class Entity\User is not a valid entity or mapped super class. Stack trace:

#0 /home/library/vendor/doctrine/2.0/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/AnnotationDriver.php(138): Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException::classIsNotAValidEntityOrMappedSuperClass('Entity\User')
#1 /home/library/vendor/doctrine/2.0/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php(282): Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver->loadMetadataForClass('Entity\User', Object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata))
#2 /home/library/vendor/doctrine/2.0/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php(176): Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata('Entity\User')
#3 /home/library/vendor/doctrine/2.0/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php(247): Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor('Entity\User')
#4 /home/library/vendor/doctrine/2.0/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php(564): Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->getClassMetadata('Entity\User')
#5 /home/imobfusion/public_html/application/modules/a1/controllers/IndexController.php(68): Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->getRepository('Entity\User')
#6 /home/library/vendor/zend/1.11.3/Zend/Controller/Action.php(513): A1_IndexController->testDoctrineAction()
#7 /home/library/vendor/zend/1.11.3/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(295): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('testDoctrineAct...')
#8 /home/library/vendor/zend/1.11.3/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#9 /home/library/vendor/zend/1.11.3/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#10 /home/library/vendor/zend/1.11.3/Zend/Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#11 /home/imobfusion/public_html/public/index.php(21): Zend_Application->run()
#12 {main}  

Request Parameters:

array(3) {   ["controller"]=>   string(5) "index"   ["action"]=>   string(13) "test-doctrine"   ["module"]=>   string(2) "a1" }
```

looikng on AnnotationDriver.php(138):

```
// Evaluate Entity annotation
if (isset($classAnnotations['Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity'])) {
   $entityAnnot = $classAnnotations['Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity'];
   $metadata->setCustomRepositoryClass($entityAnnot->repositoryClass);
} else if (isset($classAnnotations['Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappedSuperclass'])) {
   $metadata->isMappedSuperclass = true;
} else {
   throw MappingException::classIsNotAValidEntityOrMappedSuperClass($className);
}
```

**on else the exception is thrown**

but I really do not know what happens!

Any Help or Tip?

Obs:

- /home/library/ <----- this folder is the same(identical) on all servers;
- The Entity\User is correcly pointed and is the same on both servers;
- I disable cache and clear the cache before calling a Repository on Entity Manager and the erros occurss!!
- The PHP Version on last one server is 5.3.8 and on server 4(running ok) is 5.3.10.
- The errors occurs on All(18) entities on app, not only in Entity\User.

**Tracking the problem i do this on my bootstrap (var_dump(),die()):**

```
// AnnotationDriver
$driver = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver($options["entities_dir"]);
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driver);

var_dump($driver->getAllClassNames());
die();
```

And getAllClassNames() return a empty array only o server 5, this is the error, the classes is not loading on server 05, but why..??? Test Continue!!

**Tracking more i found more**

```
public function isTransient($className)
{
    $classAnnotations = $this->_reader->getClassAnnotations(new \ReflectionClass($className));
        if($className=="Entity\User")         // Debug
        {                                     // Debug  
            var_dump($classAnnotations);  // Debug
        }                                 // Debug  

    return ! isset($classAnnotations['Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity']) &&
           ! isset($classAnnotations['Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappedSuperclass']);
}
```

- This method on annotation driver return true $classAnnotations is a empty array.
- Resuming on server 05 the load off annotation failure, but why!. Continue!

Discory the problem but not solved:

I found the origin, and create this test script to confirm:

```
require_once "../application/doctrine/Entity/User.php";
$class = new ReflectionClass("Entity\User"); 
echo $class->getName();
echo $class->getDocComment();
```

Output on other servers:

Entity\User/** @Entity * @HasLifecycleCallbacks * @Table(name="user")
*/

Output on server 05:

Entity\User

->getDocComment don't work only with this especific classes and server:

User class/entity:

```
<?php
/** @Entity
 *  @HasLifecycleCallbacks
 *  @Table(name="user")
 */

namespace Entity;
use Validation;
use \DateTime;
use \LogHelper;

class User
{

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Properties                                                          //
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /**
    * @Id
    * @Column(type="integer")
    * @generatedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $type = 0;    
    /**
     * @Column(length=50)
     */
    protected $name;
    /**
     * @Column(length=50)
     */
    protected $user_name;
    /**
     * @Column(length=100)
     */
    protected $email;
    /**
     * @Column(length=14)
     */
    protected $phone;
    /**
     * @Column(length=14)
     */
    protected $cell_phone;
    /**
     * @Column(length=36)
     */
    protected $password;
    /**
     * @Column(type="text",length=1000)
     */
    protected $permissions;
    /**
     * @Column(type="text",length=1000)
     */
    protected $time_table;
    /**
     * @Column(type="text",length=1000,nullable=true)
     */
    protected $desktop;
    /**
     * @Column(type="boolean",nullable=true)
     */
    protected $chat_on = 0;    
    // Behaviors

    /**
     * @Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $created_at;
    /**
     * @Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $updated_at;
    /**
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @version
     */
    protected $version;

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Relations                                                           //
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /**
    * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Branch", inversedBy="users")
    * @JoinColumn(name="branch_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    private $branch;
    /**
    * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Property", mappedBy="captivator");
    */
    private $properties;

    /**
    * @OneToMany(targetEntity="KeyHistory", mappedBy="user");
    */
    private $key_histories;
    /**
    * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Presentation", mappedBy="user");
    */
    private $presentations;       
    /**
    * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Log", mappedBy="user");
    */
    private $logs;
    /**
    * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Chat", mappedBy="user");
    */
    private $chats;    

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // ForeingKey                                                          //
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /**
     * @Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $branch_id;

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Getters/Setters                                                     //
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public function setId($value) {$this->id = $value;}
    public function getId() {return $this->id;}
    public function setType($value) {$this->type = $value;}
    public function getType() {return $this->type;}    
    public function setName($value) {$this->name = $value;}
    public function getName() {return $this->name;}
    public function setUserName($value) {$this->user_name = $value;}
    public function getUserName() {return $this->user_name;}
    public function setEmail($value) {$this->email = $value;}
    public function getEmail() {return $this->email;}
    public function setPhone($value) {$this->phone = $value;}
    public function getPhone() {return $this->phone;}
    public function setCellPhone($value) {$this->cell_phone = $value;}
    public function getCellPhone() {return $this->cell_phone;}
    public function setPassword($value) {$this->password = $value;}
    public function getPassword() {return $this->password;}
    public function setPermissions($value) {$this->permissions = $value;}
    public function getPermissions() {return $this->permissions;}
    public function setTimeTable($value) {$this->time_table = $value;}
    public function getTimeTable() {return $this->time_table;}
    public function setDesktop($value) {$this->desktop = $value;}
    public function getDesktop() {return $this->desktop;}
    public function setChatOn($value) {$this->chat_on = $value;}
    public function getChatOn() {return $this->chat_on;}

    public function setBranch($value) {$this->branch = $value;}
    public function getBranch() {return $this->branch;}
    public function setBranchId($value) {$this->branch_id = $value;}
    public function getBranchId() {return $this->branch_id;}

    public function getCreatedAt() {return $this->created_at->format("d/m/Y H:i:s");}
    public function getUpdatedAt() {return $this->updated_at->format("d/m/Y H:i:s");}
    public function getVersion() {return $this->version;}

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Constructor                                                         //
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->created_at = $this->updated_at = new DateTime("now");
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Hooks                                                               //
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /**
     * @PrePersist
     * @PreUpdate
     */
    public function Validate()
    {
        $this->ApplyBehaviors();

        $e = new ValidationException();

        if(empty($this->name))
        {
            $e->AppendError("O Campo nome não pode ser vazio.","name");
        }

        if(empty($this->user_name))
        {
            $e->AppendError("O Campo nome de usuário não pode ser vazio.","user_name");
        }

        if(empty($this->email))
        {
            $e->AppendError("O Campo email não pode ser vazio.","email");
        }

        if($e->hasError())
            throw $e;

    }



    /**
     * @PostPersist
     */
    public function onPostPersist()
    {
        LogHelper::SaveAction(LogHelper::ACTION_ADD,LogHelper::ENTITY_USER,$this->getId());
    }

    /**
     * @PostUpdate
     */
    public function onPostUpdate()
    {
        LogHelper::SaveAction(LogHelper::ACTION_UPDATE,LogHelper::ENTITY_USER,$this->getId());
    }

    /**
     * @PreRemove
     */
    public function onPreRemove()
    {
        LogHelper::HoldId($this->id);
    }

    /**
     * @PostRemove 
     */
    public function onPostRemove()
    {
        LogHelper::SaveAction(LogHelper::ACTION_DELETE,LogHelper::ENTITY_USER,$this->id);
    }



    private function ApplyBehaviors()
    {
        $this->updated_at = new DateTime("now");
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Helpers                                                             //
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public function syncronize($data)
    {
        $this->setType($data["type"]);
        $this->setName($data["name"]);
        $this->setUserName($data["user_name"]);
        $this->setEmail($data["email"]);
        $this->setPhone($data["phone"]);
        $this->setCellPhone($data["cell_phone"]);
        $this->setPermissions($data["permissions"]);
        $this->setTimeTable($data["time_table"]);
        $this->setDesktop($data["desktop"]);
        $this->setBranchId($data["branch_id"]);
        $this->setChatOn($data["chat_on"]);
    }

    public function toArray()
    {
        $data["id"] = $this->getId();
        $data["type"] = $this->getType();
        $data["name"] = $this->getName();
        $data["user_name"] = $this->getUserName();
        $data["phone"] = $this->getPhone();
        $data["cell_phone"] = $this->getCellPhone();
        $data["email"] = $this->getEmail();
        $data["password"] = $this->getPassword();
        $data["permissions"] = $this->getPermissions();
        $data["time_table"] = $this->getTimeTable();
        $data["desktop"] = $this->getDesktop();
        $data["branch_id"] = $this->getBranchId();
        $data["chat_on"] = $this->getChatOn();

        $data["created_at"] = $this->getCreatedAt();
        $data["updated_at"] = $this->getUpdatedAt();
        return $data;
    }

}
```

Why getDocComment doe's not work with above class/entity only on server 05?
Continue....

Comment: I've had issues with autoloading of entities when taking some code out of Symfony. Try including the entity files directly from the bootstrap file and see if that helps

Answer (score 2):

Solved:

**Wrong:**

```
<?php
/** @Entity
 *  @HasLifecycleCallbacks
 *  @Table(name="user")
 */

namespace Entity;
use Validation;
use \DateTime;
use \LogHelper;
```

**Right:**

```
<?php
namespace Entity;
use Validation;
use \DateTime;
use \LogHelper;

/** @Entity
 *  @HasLifecycleCallbacks
 *  @Table(name="user")
 */
```

But on php 5.3.8 Wrong is Right, occurs only on php 5.3.10!!